# Json object returning wrong result in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

I need to get the `full address` and the `lat` and `long` values, have the following json

```js
var place = {
  "address_components": [{
      "long_name": "17",
      "short_name": "17",
      "types": [
        "street_number"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Via Gavino Alivia",
      "short_name": "Via Gavino Alivia",
      "types": [
        "route"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Sassari",
      "short_name": "Sassari",
      "types": [
        "locality",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Sassari",
      "short_name": "Sassari",
      "types": [
        "administrative_area_level_3",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Provincia di Sassari",
      "short_name": "SS",
      "types": [
        "administrative_area_level_2",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Sardegna",
      "short_name": "Sardegna",
      "types": [
        "administrative_area_level_1",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Italia",
      "short_name": "IT",
      "types": [
        "country",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "07100",
      "short_name": "07100",
      "types": [
        "postal_code"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "adr_address": "<span class=\"street-address\">Via Gavino Alivia, 17</span>, <span class=\"postal-code\">07100</span> <span class=\"locality\">Sassari</span> <span class=\"region\">SS</span>, <span class=\"country-name\">Italia</span>",
  "formatted_address": "Via Gavino Alivia, 17, 07100 Sassari SS, Italia",
  "geometry": {
    "location": {
      "lat": 40.7272074,
      "lng": 8.575266499999998
    },
    "viewport": {
      "south": 40.7258300197085,
      "west": 8.573940919708548,
      "north": 40.7285279802915,
      "east": 8.576638880291512
    }
  },
  "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
  "id": "60b613592143b21a673925a803f3a37e74692be2",
  "name": "Via Gavino Alivia, 17",
  "place_id": "ChIJ-_S-5gZk3BIRnEAF-pcOiGc",
  "reference": "CmRbAAAAak30NgQLPA1jRYRq1gaOvw2nvBaLEb7vDYYWW-8txVZE9PPm5NfqR92aVMDrz-_hpsfL3COT-5fC3jEmuWUuanEJLGp4fQAYjVeQ3KOV-jKVY1WaE1sqIzLyq_qzrrSmEhDwhG5nCw7umUscO6SunN1LGhTYgXhJnFle42TgdiUMjJV48MMl4w",
  "scope": "GOOGLE",
  "types": [
    "street_address"
  ],
  "url": "https://maps.google.com/?q=Via+Gavino+Alivia,+17,+07100+Sassari+SS,+Italia&ftid=0x12dc6406e6bef4fb:0x67880e97fa05409c",
  "utc_offset": 60,
  "vicinity": "Sassari",
  "html_attributions": []
};

console.log(place.geometry.location.lat);
console.log(place.geometry.location.lng);
console.log(place.formatted_address);
```

If I do the following to get the `lat` and `lng`:

```
console.log(place.geometry.location.lat);
console.log(place.geometry.location.lng);
```

I get :

```
ƒ (){return a}
ƒ (){return b}
```

While If I do the same for the full address is fine:

```
console.log(place.formatted_address);
```

As I get:

```
Via Gavino Alivia, 17, 07100 Sassari SS, Italia
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Full code:

```
new L.Control.GPlaceAutocomplete({
  callback: function(place){
    $(".leaflet-marker-icon, .leaflet-shadow-pane").remove();
    var loc = place.geometry.location;
    map.setView( [loc.lat(), loc.lng()], 4);
    new L.marker([loc.lat(), loc.lng()]).addTo(map);
    console.log(place.formatted_address);
    console.log(place.geometry.location.lat);
    console.log(place.geometry.location.lng);
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

Console:

```
Via Gavino Alivia, 17, 07100 Sassari SS, Italia
ƒ (){return a}
ƒ (){return b}
```

Comment: I added answer and it is working fine with `place.geometry.location.lat` and `place.geometry.location.lng`. Please check and let me know if anything else required.

Comment: I don't think there is any problem with your code posted. is there any more information that you missed in your question.

Comment: @Sreekanth yes I thought and i still think is correct too, see the updated question with the full code I am using

Comment: @rob.m This is primarily due to the googlemaps api. geometry object is not a simple json object. its an instance of https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/#PlaceGeometry . More details on the latlan could be found here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/#LatLng

Comment: @Sreekanth yes I am using gmaps and places. But yet, only if I use `console.log(place.geometry.location.lat());` works, but I am not sure why I should be using the brackets and per one of the answers

Comment: @rob.m you are not consuming a plain JSON object. it is being fed to your callback post some processing from the googlemaps api. hence, they would have abstracted the lat and lang to be methods similar to getter.

Comment: @Sreekanth i see, well accepting the answer which uses brackets then as it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to get the lat and lng :

`place.geometry.location.lat()`
`place.geometry.location.lng()`

Comment: ok thanks a lot, that works. But why should I use the brackets?

Comment: lat and long are only values...why u have used function call ?

Comment: @UditKumawat what's your take on it?

Comment: Even I am asking the same question to @Sagar

Comment: @UditKumawat sorry I meant, how would you answer my question on SO? :)

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine. Check it out below code.

```js
var place = {
    "address_components": [
        {
            "long_name": "17",
            "short_name": "17",
            "types": [
                "street_number"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "Via Gavino Alivia",
            "short_name": "Via Gavino Alivia",
            "types": [
                "route"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "Sassari",
            "short_name": "Sassari",
            "types": [
                "locality",
                "political"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "Sassari",
            "short_name": "Sassari",
            "types": [
                "administrative_area_level_3",
                "political"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "Provincia di Sassari",
            "short_name": "SS",
            "types": [
                "administrative_area_level_2",
                "political"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "Sardegna",
            "short_name": "Sardegna",
            "types": [
                "administrative_area_level_1",
                "political"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "Italia",
            "short_name": "IT",
            "types": [
                "country",
                "political"
            ]
        },
        {
            "long_name": "07100",
            "short_name": "07100",
            "types": [
                "postal_code"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "adr_address": "<span class=\"street-address\">Via Gavino Alivia, 17</span>, <span class=\"postal-code\">07100</span> <span class=\"locality\">Sassari</span> <span class=\"region\">SS</span>, <span class=\"country-name\">Italia</span>",
    "formatted_address": "Via Gavino Alivia, 17, 07100 Sassari SS, Italia",
    "geometry": {
        "location": {
            "lat": 40.7272074,
            "lng": 8.575266499999998
        },
        "viewport": {
            "south": 40.7258300197085,
            "west": 8.573940919708548,
            "north": 40.7285279802915,
            "east": 8.576638880291512
        }
    },
    "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
    "id": "60b613592143b21a673925a803f3a37e74692be2",
    "name": "Via Gavino Alivia, 17",
    "place_id": "ChIJ-_S-5gZk3BIRnEAF-pcOiGc",
    "reference": "CmRbAAAAak30NgQLPA1jRYRq1gaOvw2nvBaLEb7vDYYWW-8txVZE9PPm5NfqR92aVMDrz-_hpsfL3COT-5fC3jEmuWUuanEJLGp4fQAYjVeQ3KOV-jKVY1WaE1sqIzLyq_qzrrSmEhDwhG5nCw7umUscO6SunN1LGhTYgXhJnFle42TgdiUMjJV48MMl4w",
    "scope": "GOOGLE",
    "types": [
        "street_address"
    ],
    "url": "https://maps.google.com/?q=Via+Gavino+Alivia,+17,+07100+Sassari+SS,+Italia&ftid=0x12dc6406e6bef4fb:0x67880e97fa05409c",
    "utc_offset": 60,
    "vicinity": "Sassari",
    "html_attributions": []
};

console.log("lat", place.geometry.location.lat);
console.log("lng", place.geometry.location.lng);
console.log("address", place.formatted_address);
```

Comment: it is in your example, not in mine. Could it be as the json is a callback result? `new L.Control.GPlaceAutocomplete({
  callback: function(place){` and that's why i need to add `()` as per the other answer?

Comment: `lat` and `lng` is just a property of a `location` object. Why `()` required to access those properties ?

Comment: I do think the code is correct too, yet that's what I get in console on my end. See the updated question with the full code

Comment: @rob.m Why downvoted ? When i run the code snippet in the question it is giving proper result : `40.7272074`, `8.575266499999998`, `Via Gavino Alivia, 17, 07100 Sassari SS, Italia`

Comment: I haven't downVoted anything. Anyway yes I can see your result and the result on my question now that has been made interactive, yet the problem persist on my end and makes no sense to me